# Order by values of multiple columns combined using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table "Orders" with the following columns:

- Id
- Created (Date)
- Modified (Date)

An order always has Created date but might have or not have Modified date. Here is an example

1. 1, 2019-12-24, null
2. 2, 2019-03-13, 2020-01-10
3. 3, 2019-02-10, 2019-02-25
4. 4, 2019-01-10, null

How can I create a query that will order the orders chronologically by last interaction with them? In the example above the result should be 4, 3, 1, 2?

If I do `orders.OrderBy(o => o.Modified).ThenBy(o => o.Created)` the nulls will be 4, 1, 3, 2 because of the nulls. If I ignore them using first `OrderBy(o => o.Modified.HasValue)` then those entities will be put either in the beginning or in the end.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can further help you?

Comment: `orders.OrderBy(o => o.Modified.HasValue ? o.Modified : o.Created);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```cs
orders.OrderBy(o => o.Modified ?? o.Created);
```

Comment: [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). This is excellent!!